# Android, Except ZXing is there any other third party library for reading Qr codes?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

In my project I need to read Qr codes. I know how to call Zxing with Intent and if there was not install in device, how to direct user to android market in order to download it.

Based of request, I shouldn't use third party application therefore I decided to add zxing library to my project. Also, I know what should I do and how to add it as library. Before releasing ADT 18, I was successful to use integrate zxing as library into my other applications but i'm really amaze why I can't do it after upgrading to ADT 18. Each time compiler says Dalvik Machin encountered error 1; and nothing more.

I'm sure I set everything correctly but there is problem. Last two days I was working on it and i'm sure something has problem that I don't know what!

If you know other Or library (in .jar format) that i can integrate it to my application please tell me.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Update to ADT 19. It fixes a lot of error regarding Dalvik Machin encountered error 1

Comment: :) I think the last one is 18 (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). Am i right?

Comment: Sorry I meant the SDK tools: http://tools.android.com/release

Answer (score 1):

You can try OBSQR

https://bitbucket.org/trikita/obsqr